# Passing cookie/storage value along two different subpaths in same domain. Not able to go up one directory

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two tabs where the second tab is going to update a status which needs be transferred to the first tab. First tab will be polling that.

The paths are like:

xyz.com/path1

xyz.com/path2

I tried cookie, localstorage, sessionstorage but all of them are creating separate instances. I have to select one directory up and then reach the other path and I am clearly setting the path value wrong. What would be the correct approach and syntax. I am setting them all in js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of localStorage and listen to storage event. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event

The storage event will fire whenever there is a change in localStorage.

In path2 you have to setItem on localStorage and in path1 listen to it.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to set localstorage elsewhere properly.